# Effective way to determine position of two lines

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to determine the position of two lines, so far using numpy but I am open to use opencv if necessary.

First look at the pic
[image: lines]

I am using the means of the X coordinate. So in the first picture, you can see the blobs in the center are the position of the mean of the X coordinate for each line. You can clearly see that the red line is "to the left" of the green line (since mean_read < mean_green)

The problem is when some lines are small like in the picture to the right.
You can intuitively know that the red line is still "to the left" of the green line. However if we see the means, this time mean_red > mean_green.

Is there a better method using numpy or even using opencv to correctly determine that the green line is to the right of the red line?

Comment: you can use `inRange` from `OpenCV` to separate the colors in **HSV** space, the other solution using `Numpy`  in RGB space is to separate the color channels and find the mean at the Red channel separately from the mean of the Green channel

Comment: What's your (mathematical) definition of "line segment A is to the left of line segment B"? How would it work if, say, the green segment was horizontal? What if the segments cross? What if, in the second picture, the red segment was even further up?

Comment: See https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/542870-determine-which-side-of-a-line-a-point-is/  But you really need to test both end points of the red line, because it may slant and cross over the green line.

Comment: @Bilal Sorry if I were not clear enough. The lines and their coordinates are already clearly identified, so it is not a matter of finding the red or green ones. that is already done. The problem is the means are not always a good judge

Comment: @KansaiRobot If you have the coordinates then what is the need for OpenCV and image-processing tags? From now on, it seems to be a simple matter. Maybe you just need to compare the two ends of both lines (not their center point). For more reassurance, it might be better to ask this question at math.stackexchange.com based on your recent comment.

Answer (score 1):

This idea works if the intersection of the lines does not matter to you if they extend.

```py
im = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/im.png')
gr = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bw = cv2.threshold(gr, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(~bw, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
gMid, g1, g2, gColor = None, None, None, (100, 255, 50)
rMid, r1, r2, rColor = None, None, None, (100, 50, 255)
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (127, 127, 127), 2)
    ROI = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    if np.mean(ROI[:, :, 1]) > np.mean(ROI[:, :, 2]): # Green line
        g1, g2 = ((x, y), (x+w, y+h))[:2] if ROI[0, 0, 0] == 255 else ((x+w, y), (x, y+h))[:2]
        gMid = (x+w//2, y+h//2)
    else: # red line
        r1, r2 = ((x, y), (x+w, y+h))[:2] if ROI[0, 0, 0] == 255 else ((x+w, y), (x, y+h))[:2]
        rMid = (x+w//2, y+h//2)

# Draw coordinates of green line
for p in [gMid, g1, g2]:
    cv2.circle(im, p, 20, gColor, 5)

# Draw coordinates of red line
for p in [rMid, r1, r2]:
    cv2.circle(im, p, 20, rColor, 5)

# Swap (Sort) green line start and end points
if r1[0]>r2[0]:
    r1,r2=r2,r1

# Swap (Sort) red line start and end points
if g1[0]>g2[0]:
    g1,g2=g2,g1

if r1[0] < g1[0] and r2[0] < g2[0]:
    print("x-axis --- Red line is left")
elif r1[0] > g1[0] and r2[0] > g2[0]:
    print("x-axis --- Green line is left")
elif r1[0] > g1[0] and r2[0] < g2[0]:
    print("x-axis --- Red is inside Green zone")
else:
    print("Something else")
```

Visual Output:

[image]

Printed Output:

```py
# For left sample:
# x-axis --- Red line is left


# For right sample:
# x-axis --- Red is inside Green zone
```

Now other situations may occur. If we continue the lines, the lines will intersect if they are not parallel. If you want to know in which position the lines will be relative to each other. First you need to [calculate the equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) of both lines. And then for intersection point, search [LineLineIntersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) to find related mathematical equations.